# Objective-C Exponent Method Failure

Tags: objective-c, math

For practice I decided to make an exponent method that handles things like if I wanted to do 20^2 which is 20*20 so of course this should come out to 400. Here is my method:

```
 #import "Math.h"

 @implementation Math

 +(double)exponent:(double)n :(int)e{
     double product = n;
     for(int x=0; x<e; x++){
         product *= product;
     }
     return product;
 }

 @end
```

So then I use it like so:

```
         double product = [Math exponent:20 :2];
         NSLog(@"product = %g",product);
```

Strangely this comes out as 160000 every time rather than 400. What have I done incorrectly?

I understand there is no exponential operator in Objective-C but then what is '^' for. I used it to do 20^2 but it came out as 22. Why is this?

Thanks for y'alls help!

Comment: In C-based languages, `^` is *not* exponentation. It is instead the XOR (exclusive OR) bitwise operator. It is easy for novices to get these confused. See [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/) for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your for loop is wrong.

```
double product = n;
for(int x=0; x<e; x++){
    product *= product;
}
```

Original value:
product = 20.

x=0;
product = product * product. (That is product = 20 * 20 = 400)

x=1;
product = product * product. (That is product = 400 * 400 = 160000)

Your loop should be:

```
double product = n;
for(int x=1; x<e; x++){
    product *= n;
}
```

Note that the for loop starts with x = 1 and that product `product *= n;`
This way:
product = 20.

x=0;
product = product * e. (That is product = 20 * 20 = 400)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pow(n, e)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/pow/) instead of implementing your own one. This is a C method defined in `math.h`. Since Objective-C is superset of C language, you can use it with C syntax without problem:

```
double product = pow(20, 2);
NSLog(@"product = %lf", product);
```

BTW, what's wrong in your own implementation is that you did `product *= product` for `e` times. Correct statement should be `product *= n`.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate it! I am aware of pow but in the book I use it advised, for practice, that I created my own.

Answer (score 1):

@jer_francis, this isn't an answer to this question, but I saw that you asked a question on what made up a good software development laptop, that got moderated out of existence.

I am going to suggest that you check out [The Tech Guy](http://www.techguylabs.com/). This is a radio show that is broadcast nationwide, the Tech Guy being Leo Laporte.  He is not personally a dev, but he has a wide knowledge of technology and could probably give you some good suggestions.

You'd have to call in to the show (it is on weekends only), but you stand a good chance of getting in, if you're persistent.  If the show doesn't air near enough to you for you to listen on-air, you can still listen online.  It's interesting to listen to, on top of everything else.

**Everybody**: Sorry about putting this in as an answer, but I wasn't sure I'd be able to do a decent job of directing this young man to a good source to help him answer his non-SO-appropriate question that got deleted.